# what will happen when an array is initialized more than once in c++?

Tags: c++

What happens to the memory location when I initialize a variable in c++ more than once? For example:

```
LPWSTR sampleString = new whcar_t[10];
//some operations here
sampleString = new wchar_t[2];
//some operations here
sampleString = new wchar_t[25];
//some operations here
```

If I delete the memory by using `delete [] sampleString;` will all the associated memory locations be cleared?

Comment: If you pair each `new[]` with a `delete[]`, you should be fine, and as mentioned, doing so before the next `new[]`. Once you use `new[]` again, the old area of memory is lost, but still not free if you didn't `delete[]` it.

Comment: @chris, not enough. You should pair them, and also make sure that after each `new`, a `delete` is called **before** the next `new`.

Comment: @littleadv, Oops, I meant that, but it didn't come out too clearly. I fixed it up a little.

Comment: You don't *initialize an array*, you **assign a value to a pointer variable**

Comment: You can't initialize anything more than once in C++.  You are creating several dynamically allocated arrays, and assigning the address of each to a pointer.  (There is actual never any reason to do this in C++; I've yet to see a case where there wasn't a better solution than array new.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, only the last one. All the rest will be lost forever. This is what is called "a memory leak".

Comment: Will the memory that is allocated first two times be freed automatically or it will be unusable?

Comment: It will be unusable to you (the usability to other processes depends on the OS memory management)

Comment: @user921207, C++ has no garbage collector. The best you can do is smart pointers, which free the memory by themselves under different circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to pair each `new[]` with a separate `delete[]`.

In your example, the first two allocations will be lost. A memory leak.

Comment: see my comment to chris. While people who know the answer will understand what you mean, people who don't - might not.

Answer (score 0):

No you all the previously allocated memory are lost. you should consider using smart pointer

Answer (score 0):

notice that using a smart pointer is good if you point it to an object and NOT an array. 
if you wrap the array with struct/class that will be ok.
you can also use STL Vector (with a smart pointer of your choice)

Answer (score 0):

> If I delete the memory by using delete [] sampleString; will all the associated memory locations be cleared?

No, how can it sampleString can only store a single reference at a time so when you send it to `delete []` it knows only of the last one.

Since `C++` by default doesn't have garbage collection you have to manually take care of memory management, when manually allocating/deallocating.

As some have pointed it out, you may want to use a smart pointers.